# Android - Get Local IP Address when using wifi, hotspot, usb or bluetooth sharing

Tags: java, android

I need the local IP Address of my Android phone when the hotspot is on or connected to a wifi network or via Bluetooth.

**I already used these two codes**

*First code gives "10.0.2.5" in all condition and Second one giving correct IP address when connecting to the wifi network. But when hotspot is on it give "0.0.0.0"*

**FIRST code snippet**

```
public static String getIpAddress() {
    try {
        for (Enumeration en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
            NetworkInterface intf = (NetworkInterface) en.nextElement();
            for (Enumeration enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                InetAddress inetAddress = (InetAddress) enumIpAddr.nextElement();

                if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
                    String ipAddress = inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();
                    Log.e("IP address", "" + ipAddress);
                    return ipAddress;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        Log.e("MASOOM", ex.toString());
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Second code snippet**

```
public String getIpAddress(){
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    int ipAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress();
    return String.format("%d.%d.%d.%d", (ipAddress & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 8 & 0xff),(ipAddress >> 16 & 0xff), (ipAddress >> 24 & 0xff));
}
```

**Please provide the correct code**

Answer (score 0):

```
String ip = "";
        try {
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces.nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
                while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();
                    if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
                        ip += inetAddress.getHostAddress() + " | ";
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ip;
```